# Append data to an html page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

In jQuery, how can I add some data to a div so that when the html page loads, the data is executed?

I have the following html code:

```
<script src="objects/control.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<span id="customdata">

</span>
```

I am wanting the following:

```
<span id="customdata">
  <script src="objects/customobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="objects/customitem1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="objects/customitem2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</span>
```

Here is my objects/control.js code:

```
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customitem1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customitem2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

I have an alert in the `objects/customitem1.js file`, and when the page loads, this alert is not displaying.

What is incorrect with my code?

Thanks

Comment: do you see any errors in your console ? also place the script with control.js  below the span.

Answer (score 0):

Try put backslash before closing tag like example below :

```
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customobject.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customitem1.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
$('#customdata').append('<script src="objects/customitem2.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>');
```

It all because of parsing problems. `</script>` has avoid the special character by using backslash otherwise it would end the enclosing `<script></script>` block too early in this case.

Comment: You should explain why this is needed.